# Merging inputs in distributed application

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, distributed, bigdata

**INTRODUCTION**

I have to write distributed application which counts maximum number of unique values for 3 records. I have no experience in such area and don't know frameworks at all. My input could looks as follow:

```
u1: u2,u3,u4,u5,u6
u2: u1,u4,u6,u7,u8
u3: u1,u4,u5,u9
u4: u1,u2,u3,u6
...
```

Then beginning of the results should be:

```
(u1,u2,u3), u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9 => count=6
(u1,u2,u4), u3,u5,u6,u7,u8    => count=5
(u1,u3,u4), u2,u5,u6,u9       => count=4
(u2,u3,u4), u1,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9 => count=6
...
```

So my approach is to first merge each two of records, and then merge each merged pair with each single record.

**QUESTION**

Can I do such operation like working (merge) on more than one input row on the same time in framewors like hadoop/spark? Or maybe my approach is incorrect and I should do this different way?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `So my approach is to first merge each two of records, and then merge each merged pair with each single record.` This is exactly what a reducer does in a typical Map Reduce framework (such as Spark, or Hadoop MR), by applying a merging function to the values.

Comment: @Hawknight From MapReduce Tutorial on Hadoop page: "Reducer reduces a set of intermediate values which share a key to a smaller set of values." It's not covered in my case because I want to not really merge records, but more combine them with each other. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood correctly what you are looking to achieve, but ultimately it's up to you to define how you want your data to be processed. If want you need is to process at one time multiple lines in your input, you'll need to define your own InputFormat that will read a set number of lines and feed it into your map operation. However, a more common use case would be to pre-process the data to combine your lines together, and then run a map reduce batch on them. Or to do a first map reduce batch to sort out your data as wanted and then reduce the results by key.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do such operation like working (merge) on more than one input row on the same time in framewors like hadoop/spark?

Yes, you can.

> Or maybe my approach is incorrect and I should do this different way?

It depends on the size of the data. If your data is small, it's faster and easier to do it locally. If your data is huge, at least hundreds of GBs, the common strategy is to save the data to HDFS(distributed file system), and do analysis using Mapreduce/Spark.

A example spark application written in scala:

```
    object MyCounter {
      val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My Counter")
      val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val inputFile = sc.textFile("hdfs:///inputfile.txt")
        val keys = inputFile.map(line => line.substring(0, 2)) // get "u1" from "u1: u2,u3,u4,u5,u6"

        val triplets = keys.cartesian(keys).cartesian(keys)
          .map(z => (z._1._1, z._1._2, z._2))
          .filter(z => !z._1.equals(z._2) && !z._1.equals(z._3) && !z._2.equals(z._3)) // get "(u1,u2,u3)" triplets

        // If you have small numbers of (u1,u2,u3) triplets, it's better prepare them locally.

        val res = triplets.cartesian(inputFile).filter(z => {
          z._2.startsWith(z._1._1) || z._2.startsWith(z._1._2) || z._2.startsWith(z._1._3)
        }) // (u1,u2,u3) only matches line starts with u1,u2,u3, for example "u1: u2,u3,u4,u5,u6"
          .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b) // merge three lines
          .map(z => {
          val line = z._2
          val values = line.split(",")
          //count unique values using set
          val set = new util.HashSet[String]()
          for (value <- values) {
            set.add(value)
          }
          "key=" + z._1 + ", count=" + set.size()  // the result from one mapper is a string
        }).collect()

        for (line <- res) {
          println(line)
        }
      }
    }
```

1. The code is not tested. And is not efficient. It can have some optimization (for example, remove unnecessary map-reduce steps.)
2. You can rewrite the same version using Python/Java.
3. You can implement the same logic using Hadoop/Mapreduce